# Sending username and password as md5 hash for every request from iPhone game

Tags: security, session

I am building a simple iPhone game which has a community maps feature.

Users sign up for an account with just their email and password, and then they can build, upload and download custom maps.

Now I know that sending the username and password with every request is usually a bad idea, but it is a lot easier for development instead of having to deal with login session, and I think it is okay for situations where security isn't a major concern.

The most important thing is to protect the user's password as they likely use the same password for multiple accounts.

So the simple approach I think is this: Send the user's username and password as one md5 hash with every request. Would this be okay?

Sure there is a risk someone might hijack the request, but login sessions have the same risk. And if a hacker got hold of a user's login session, don't they just need to force that user to log off so the client will send the user's username and password in the next request?

Comment: From a security standpoint, an MD5 hashed password is probably never ok...

Comment: Good point. I should probably use SHA512 instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't got any experience with mobile app development, however some general principles still apply. Firstly MD5 is flawed, don't use it. And if you are going to use a different algo (depends on your choice, and what what security/speed you are looking for, for thing like that I'd probably go for blowfish, but SHA512 should also do the job), definitely use salts.

I still think though that a simple session management would be better than sending the login information with every request, simple random session id should do (you generate it upon log in and associate with a particular user); of course there you run in a trouble with randomness of the ids (if they are predictable it is obviously a problem).

But I suppose the major point here is how will the app communicate with the server; if it is encrypted (HTTPS I would presume) you should be fine either way, I think is more important than whether you use sessions or hashed login info. And usage of HTTPS should take care of your worries about request/session hijacking as well (unless someone cracks the encryption with 200 modified PS3 units :) )